# Symfony Doctrine Schema Segmentation Fault

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, segmentation-fault

I'm setting up my first symfony project, and am having trouble with the schema. I'm not sure if I'm going about it the right way.

I'm having a problem with two of my classes. I have Clients, which can have many Contacts, one of the contacts needs to be selected as the invoice contact. This is my schema:

```
NativeClient:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    name:                { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    address:             { type: string(255) }
    postcode:            { type: string(9) }
    tel:                 { type: string(50) }
    fax:                 { type: string(50) }
    website:             { type: string(255) }
    client_status_id:    { type: integer, notnull: true, default: 0 }
    priority:            { type: boolean, notnull: true, default: 0 }
    invoice_contact_id:  { type: integer }
    invoice_method_id:   { type: integer }
  relations:
    NativeContact:       { local: invoice_contact_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: NativeInvoiceContacts }
    NativeClientStatus:  { local: client_status_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: NativeContacts }
    NativeInvoiceMethod: { local: invoice_method_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: NativeClientStatuses }


NativeContact:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    client_id:          { type: integer, notnull: true }
    name:               { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    position:           { type: string(255) }
    tel:                { type: string(50), notnull: true }
    mobile:             { type: string(50) }
    email:              { type: string(255) }
  relations:
    NativeClient:       { onDelete: CASCADE, local: client_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: NativeClients } 

NativeClientStatus:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    name:               { type: string(255), notnull: true }

NativeInvoiceMethod:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    name:               { type: string(255), notnull: true }
```

If i remove the following line (and associated fixtures) it works, otherwise I get a segmentation fault.

```
NativeContact:       { local: invoice_contact_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: NativeInvoiceContacts }
```

Could it be getting in a loop? Trying to reference the Client and the Contact over and over? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Darren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Darren, it seems like you're defining the relationship at both ends while using conflicting criteria...

```
NativeContact:       { local: invoice_contact_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: NativeInvoiceContacts }
```

...relationship is between "invoice_contact_id" and undeclared "id" PK in NativeContact.

```
 NativeClient:       { onDelete: CASCADE, local: client_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: NativeClients }
```

... same relationship is between "client_id" and undeclared "id" PK in NativeClient.

I personally only define these in one end and let Doctrine handle the rest, but it depends on what you're trying to achieve here. If ONE client HAS MANY contacts, you could drop the second declaration and define the relationship in the clients table only and add "type: many, foreignType: one" to state that it's a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: OK, so it looks like I'm going about it the wrong way. Is there a getting the following structure: 

- There are many Clients; 
- Each Client can have many Contacts; 
- One of those Contacts can be the Invoice Contact; 

Will I need to use a bridge Class, like ClientInvoiceContact, which has the ID of the Client and Contact in only? That just sounds superfluous, when the Client could store the Contact ID in it. 

I know it could be seen as a circular reference, which is probably where the code is having difficulties, but in essence I'm wanting to set one of the Contacts as 'primary'.

Answer (score 3):

Old question I know, but heres a follow up solution. Sometimes Doctrine will throw this error for seemingly no reason whatsoever. Im sure there is an underlying reason, but we dont all have time to debug the entire Doctrine source.

Try specifying --env=[your env], and it may just work - has for me.

Comment: Very, very nice workaround. Agree about debugging. I thought an ORM was supposed to be less work, but that's simply not the case with doctrine. You do get a lot less forgotten WHERE's though.

Comment: Thanks Vertigo. I've been using Symfony 1.4 + Doctrine 1.2 for 5 years now and never had this bug show up until today for some reason. Segfault unless I specify the environment.